# List of constants to Binding Adapter method

Tags: android, data-binding, android-binding-adapter

I'm using all up-to-date Android's features like AndroidX, JetPack etc.

And I would like to create my custom BindingAdapter, passing list of typed values from enum through layout. It should looks like that:

```
            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                app:values="@{ [E.First, E.Second] } />
```

Where `E` is my enum:

```
enum class E { First, Second }
```

So, I'm wondering, is there some way to define array/list in layout using DataBinding features, and how to pass it to the BindingAdapter method?

P.S. Of course, I know that I can do it passing as variable via binding from Activity/Fragment, but I would like to keep my code clean :)